# Cannot change UIBarButtonItem color attribute in disabled state

Tags: iphone, ios8

I have created a UIToolBar with three bar button items.  All works well when using the default font and font size.  However, the font is a bit too large and I want to resize it.  I used the following code to successfully customize the font size and color in the normal state, but when, say, button #1 is disabled  the text color remains black for both the enabled and disabled states  - i.e. it doesn't change color to gray.

```
NSDictionary *ena = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
                           [UIColor blackColor]};
NSDictionary *dis = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
                            [UIColor grayColor]};

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:ena forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:dis forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

I'd appreciate some feedback on where I went wrong with the above code.

Answer (score -1):

Create an outlet for the barButtonItem; suppose it is myBarButton. Disable it initially from the storyboard. Then call this in ViewDidLoad()

```
if (myBarButton.enabled == 'NO') {
     NSDictionary *dis = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
                                [UIColor grayColor]}; 
     [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:ena forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Then after doing some job when necessary enable myBarButton, then run the code below

```
 NSDictionary *dis = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
                            [UIColor blackColor]}; 
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:ena forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Actually, UIControlStateDisabled is not working as I observed.